# User-friendly, non-technical way to upload bulk data

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm building a system using FuelPHP in which users can download a CSV template, populate it, then upload it to mass import records into a database. I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel with this one, although I don't see any implementations.

What is the best/standard/right/slick way to allow users who are generally non-technical to upload bulk data?

Comment: Use other program's export feature?

Comment: dont allow people who are non technical to upload data

Comment: The best/standard/right/slick way is to get them to email you the data, then you import it and send back all the errors. There will be errors.

Answer (score 1):

Non-technical end users loading their own data + mass import into database = very bad idea

Seriously, Build into your template clear instructions and **limit** the options/data types the user can add.   Then, double dog check the data and be prepared to fail gracefully.

If data passes inspection (is sanitized) - use standard PHP techniques to guard against injection - [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)